# How can I dynamically center a div between tiled divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

The design is responsive, then there will be tiled divs (variable number). My Problem is how can I keep one of the div always center horizontally and vertically but must flow along with other divs.

So the centered div must dynamically move to make itself centered if the screen is resized.

I have used jquery to acheived the centered div, but it is position absolute. The challenge is how to acheive the centered div with relative position but dynamically move to center if page is resized.

Comment: What did you try? If you google your problem, it will lead you to tutorials like this : http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

Comment: @Jeremy, Thanks.  I have tried using Jquery like this.

    $('.mybox').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : -$('.mybox').outerWidth()/2,
        'margin-top' : -$('.mybox').outerHeight()/2
       }); 
  
This centers the div with the class mybox. but it is positioned as absolute so it flows away from the rest of the surrounding boxes.  But what I need is that it must be relative to the other boxes. but maintain a centered status no matter how many boxes will be added.

Comment: I don't really get the concept. It must be absolutely centered in the screen, but relative to other boxes... That sounds incompatible. Anyway you don't need jQuery for this, just use `{ left:50%; top:50%; transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); }` in CSS.